# How to undo a git pull?

Tags: git, undo, pull

I would like to undo my git pull on account of unwanted commits on the remote origin, but I don't know to which revision I have to reset back to.

How can I just go back to the state before I did the git pull on the remote origin?

Comment: Side note: you may find it useful to `git fetch upstream` first, then take a quick look at `git diff upstream/branch` to see what you will be merging in. If all is well, then proceed with `git merge upstream/branch`

Comment: You will lose all your street cred and be docked a week's pay if any hipster brogrammer sees you do **git** commands from a GUI, but both **GitHub Desktop** and **Atom** have safe, straightforward buttons to `undo` commits and checkboxes to easily and clearly stage and unstage files.  GUIs are people too!

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Or to make it more explicit than the other answer:

```
git pull
```

whoops?

```
git reset --keep HEAD@{1}
```

Versions of git older than 1.7.1 do not have `--keep`. If you use such version, you could use `--hard` - but that is a dangerous operation because it loses any local changes.

---

[**To the commenter**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git/967611#967611)

> ORIG_HEAD is previous state of HEAD, set by commands that have possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them. It is less useful now that Git has reflog: HEAD@{1} is roughly equivalent to ORIG_HEAD (HEAD@{1} is always last value of HEAD, ORIG_HEAD is last value of HEAD before dangerous operation)

Comment: `HEAD@{1}` at that point would be the same as `orig_head`, no? EDIT: found an excellent answer ("Yes, kind of the same") to that question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git

Comment: what is the difference between HEAD@{1} and HEAD^ ?

Comment: @hugemeow That would be a fine SO question. Meanwhile [`man git-rev-parse`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) describes this. `HEAD@{1}` is the previous value of symbolic `HEAD` in the [`reflog`](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) whereas `HEAD^` is the (first) _parent revision_ of the current `HEAD`. These two need nod be equivalent (e.g. after a rebase, a hard reset, a branch switch and such things). Do read the linked article for reflog. Cheers

Comment: PowerShell users, escape the brackets with a backtick: ``git reset HEAD@`{1`}``

Comment: http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html I think you have wanted to type `HEAD@\`{1\`}`, or for that matter do what works on POSIX shells too: `'HEAD@{1}'`

Comment: git was definitely authored by /bin/bash users. "git reset HEAD@{1}" is hostile syntax for csh derivatives.

Comment: I think it not only reset the pull, but also my commits =(

Comment: I had to use  `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`

Comment: you might need to do `git checkout -- .` after that. But be careful that will discard all changes in working directory

Comment: `git reset` does not remove files and directories added by the pull.
`git reset --hard` destroys my local changes.
Is there way just to undo the damage an erroneous git pull caused?

Comment: @jmster you apparently had local changes before doing the pull?. I use `autostash` for this kind of situation. Git will print the ids of automatically created stashes. I'm surprised you can pull with local changes. Maybe it's just something I automatically avoid

Comment: @sehe Yes, I usually have local changes. git pull (without --rebase) does not care about them unless it needs to overwrite some file. I will try out rebase.autostash, thank you.

Comment: `git reset` does not do the right thing here: it changes what `HEAD` points to, but not the content of the worktree. Others suggested `git checkout` or `git reset --hard`, but both are dangerous commands that destroy any uncommitted changes. I suggest using `git reset --keep HEAD@{1}` instead: `--keep` instructs git to keep uncommitted changes, but it does change the worktree.

Comment: @MatthieuMoy adding. I think that flag was added later, but yeah, that's nice to have

Comment: I disagree with the new sentence. `git reset` was wrong even without local changes: it does not change the worktree at all (i.e. it does not "reset" the merge in local files). You want `--keep` anyway (or, if you like loosing data, `--hard` but I wouldn't recommend it in any case).

Comment: @MatthieuMoy Yeah. Strangely, `--hard` is what I always used. No clue why I didn't mention it before. Cheers.

Comment: Good, now I fully agree with the answer. Thanks. For completeness I've added the version of Git where `--keep` was introduced.

Comment: don't do it!! it totally screw up local

Comment: It is much better than `git reset --hard` & then checkout modified files

Comment: This question and answer is already explained here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1223354/10373693

Comment: @sehe Your answer saved me so much work I almost lost after mistakenly applied pull --rebase from an empty repository. Thank you so much, sir! I owe you a beer :)

Comment: is ORIG_HEAD a keyword recognized by git or is it just a name you choose to refer to the head before the pull?

Comment: @FrankPuck It's recognized by Git: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse (actually just noticed I linked to **and** quoted the relevant explanation in the answer text. Oh well)

Answer (score 84):

`git reflog show` should show you the history of HEAD. You can use that to figure out where you were before the `pull`. Then you can `reset` your `HEAD` to that commit.

Comment: git reflog show gave this output: c9e5e4d HEAD@{0}: pull : Fast forward
1c86a22 HEAD@{1}: pull origin master: Fast forward
05c141a HEAD@{2}: pull : Fast forward
Can I safely reset the HEAD to HEAD@{1}

Comment: The other answer by sehe has details on how to get there.

Comment: This was super-useful after a disastrous commit somehow interspersed merge commits into my history. Got them out by looking for a last-known good in the reflog and then force pushing.

Comment: What if `pull` is the first action? If `pull` is at `HEAD@{1}`, and nothing else before that, how do you revert to a state before that?

Comment: Recreate the repository?

Answer (score 47):

This worked for me.

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Undo a merge or pull:

```
$ git pull                         (1)
Auto-merging nitfol
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in nitfol
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git reset --hard                 (2)
$ git pull . topic/branch          (3)
Updating from 41223... to 13134...
Fast-forward
$ git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD       (4)
```

Checkout this: [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) for more.

Answer (score 21):

Find the `<SHA#>` for the commit you want to go. You can find it in github or by typing `git log` or `git reflog show` at the command line and then do 
`git reset --hard <SHA#>`

Comment: Find the what for the commit?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that ```<SHA#>```

Comment: This is the command I use the most when I have to undo something

Answer (score 11):

to undo **git pull**

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

takes your local repo back to previous commit state. (Note: HEAD^ means the first immediate parent of the tip of the current branch. HEAD^ is short for HEAD^1, and you can also go further up if you want (e.g.  HEAD^2 , HEAD^3 ...).
after reset, if some unknown files left (files that arrived as a result of original git pull), they will be listed as untracked files and you can clean them up using

```
  git clean -fd
```

Answer (score 9):

Even though the above solutions do work, This answer is for you in case you want to reverse the clock instead of undoing a  git pull. I mean if you want to get your exact repo the way it was `X` Mins back then run this command

`git reset --hard branchName@{"X Minutes ago"}`

Note: before you actually go ahead and run this command please only try this command if you are sure about the time you want to go back to and heres about my situation.

I was currently on a branch `develop`, I was supposed to checkout to a new branch and pull in another branch lets say Branch `A`  but I accidentally ran
`git pull origin A` before checking out.

so to undo this change I tried this command

`git reset --hard develop@{"10 Minutes ago"}`

if you are on windows cmd and get [error: unknown switch `e](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/issues/106)

try adding quotes  like this

`git reset --hard 'develop@{"10 Minutes ago"}'`

Answer (score 4):

From https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-Undoamergeorpullinsideadirtyworkingtree

> Undo a merge or pull inside a dirty working tree
>
> ```
> $ git pull           (1)
> Auto-merging nitfol
> Merge made by recursive.
>  nitfol               |   20 +++++----
>  ...
> $ git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD      (2)
> ```
>
> Even if
>   you may have local modifications in your working tree, you can safely
>   say `git pull` when you know that the change in the other branch does
>   not overlap with them.
>
> After inspecting the result of the merge, you may find that the change
>   in the other branch is unsatisfactory. Running `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`
>   will let you go back to where you were, but it will discard
>   your local changes, which you do not want. `git reset --merge` keeps
>   your local changes.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345382/621690

Answer (score 3):

Reset the master branch:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```