# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by X commits. How to find the X commits?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-log

I was checking the X commits using the following command:

```
git log --author=<my-name> -<X>
```

But the problem is that I accidentally pulled code from another repository and added the commits from the repository to my local git repository.

So I cannot use the above command since the new commits contains some other authors.

Comment: if your working copy is clean (no uncommitted changes) you can go back to the state before pull with http://stackoverflow.com/q/1223354/11343

Comment: @CharlesB "git reset --hard" won't take to the state before pull. The message still comming.

Comment: you need to find the commit hash of the commit checked-out before pull and pass it to `reset --hard`, please read the question I referred

Comment: What do you mean with "X commits" the amount of commits that exist locally but not remotely? The amount of commits created by you? The question is a bit ambiguous about what you seek.

Comment: @LopSae the amount of commits that exist locally but not remotely.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The command

```
git log origin/master..master
```

shows the commits that are on `master` but not on `origin/master`.

Comment: It won't show the commits. It shows some commits exists in my local repository and in my remote repository.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question then...

Comment: Accepting the answer based on the votes you got :D

Answer (score 3):

I made an alias for this command that lists the commits that have not been pushed.

> > git log --branches --not --remotes --decorate --oneline

which is a variation of a command cxreg posted in [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits).

Lots of other useful ways to parse the commit tree in that post as well.

Answer (score 1):

The `treeish..treeish` notation works exactly to see the commits that are present in the second reference, but not in the first one. From the git log help:

> A regular D..M computes the set of commits that are ancestors of M, but excludes the ones that are ancestors of D. This is useful to see what happened to the history leading to M since D, in the sense that "what does M have that did not exist in D".

Using this with either `git log` or `git show` you can output a list that contains a single line for each commit pressent in the `D..M` difference:

```
git show -s --oneline branch..HEAD
```

or

```
git log --oneline branch..HEAD
```

Pair that with a word count and you can output exactly the number of commits you are looking for:

```
git log --oneline branch..HEAD | wc -l
```

Comment: I tried the above commands. I am not getting any output at all.

Comment: If you are not getting any errors and the `show/log` like the above print nothing, then it means that, assuming `A..B`, `B` already contains all the commits in `A`, and this there are no commits to print. Try inverting it, or try it with a couple commits of which you are certain of the difference. For example, if you try it with `HEAD^..HEAD` you must get a single commit displayed.

Comment: The above all comments comparing with the local repo only. how to compare with remote repo?

Comment: Use a reference with the format `remote/branch`, just like `origin/master`. If your local and remote branch are named the same and your remote is `origin`, then you could do `origin/branch..branch`. Following what you describe in the question, you might want `origin/master..HEAD`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has be answered already in another post:

```
git log origin/master..HEAD
```

(see [Viewing Unpushed Git Commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016901/viewing-unpushed-git-commits))

Answer (score -1):

I use this:

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
```

It shows commits as a graph, with all the branches and their names.

My advice is to create alias for it in ~/.gitconfig

Comment: I think it contains the commits. But it shows too much information. How can identify the X Commits from it?

Comment: You can of course add `--author=<my-name> -<X>` to it. Or isn't it what you wanted?