# Delete live site and pull in new code from repo

Tags: git

I have a local development environment and a live server. On that same server in my home directory I have a git repository. To date I've been moving files over, one at a time, via FTP. `Yuck`.

When I SSH to the server and issue the pull request I get a bunch of merge conflicts. Since I know what I committed and pushed to the repo is only and all of what I want, is there a way to wipe out what's currently on the production server and pull in everything from the repo?

I don't care about any old commit history, etc - I'm just hoping for a way to do this with limited, or hopefully no downtime. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Undo git pull, how to bring repos to old state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow - I'm not trying to bring it to an old state, I'm trying to ignore it's current state and bring it to a completely new state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git fetch --all`
`git reset --hard origin/master`

But be careful that this will overwrite your local files in production server.

Comment: Thanks, this made sense once I did it. Everything's working smoothly!

Answer (score 0):

On the live server do

```
git reset --hard master
```

This will reset to last good pushed state.

To reset to state of your remote repo use `origin/master` instead of `master`.