# Potential Git/Rails Disaster: Web page no longer loading

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I have spent a lot of time working on a webpage and have been very lazy about committing things to Git.  Today, I attempted to push everything up to my repo, but I think I may have caused a disaster.  I am very new to Git and basically just use it for its most basic functions.

I was unable to `push` anything and the console recommended using a `pull` request, after doing that and attempting to push again, I began to get a bunch of merge conflicts with my `gemfile` and `gemfile.lock`.  I tried fixing this issue as well but then I started seeing random `<<<<<<HEAD` throughout my files (including `routes` as well as my javascript).

Now when I try to load my localhost page, I seem to have all my content, but my css file will not load resulting in a very ugly page.  When I use chrome devtools and try to look at the sources, the `application.css.scss` is blank, when mine have 1000+ lines of code (and is viewable in the `app\assets\stylesheets` folder.

Has anyone had something like this happen / know how to remedy the amount of damage I might've done in 15 min.  Anything will help as I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: You need to learn how to resolve merge conflicts properly and what those "random" <<<<<HEAD actually mean. Are you working in a team ? Fetching regularly is good practice and avoids getting into this kind of problem

Comment: You can use git to go back to a point before your disastrous merge. The scss is never served, did you forget to compile the scss to css ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll want to try doing a `git reset --hard` to reset your local repo to the state it was at before you ran `git pull`.

see this answer for reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1223385/3880374

also, in case you're curious about those "random" `<<<<<<HEAD` strings throughout your files, those are actually added by Git. Per their [docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging):

> Git adds standard conflict-resolution markers to the files that have conflicts, so you can open them manually and resolve those conflicts

Github also has a [helpful guide](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-from-the-command-line/) to resolving these conflicts via the command line.