# `git pull origin master` into my checkout feature branch

Tags: git, github

I have a created a `feature` branch from `master`.

A week before, after completing my `feature` branch work say a message `This branch has conflicts with the base branch` in my pull request

To resolve these conflicting files, I did `git pull origin master` into my `feature` branch.
Now I am seeing all the commits from `master` is pulled into my branch and my pull request shows all my work additionally others work as well.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pulling (fetch + merge), you can instead:

- reset again your feature branch to [what it was before the pull](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1223354/6309)
  (try `git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`, or, if it is not working, `git reflog` + `git reset --hard HEAD@{x}`, with `x` being the number seen in reflog)
- try a rebase instead:

  ```
  git checkout feature
  git fetch
  git rebase origin/master
  git push --force
  ```

Comment: Already pushed merge commits to my branch. Still, i can do this?

Comment: Sure, the push force will rewrite your feature branch and update the pull request