# Shall I clean up the commits on my feature branch which partially undo one another?

Tags: git

On my local feature branch,

1. I did some work in a commit, and then manually edited some files to undo some of the work, and committed the undo work into two new commits. Right after making each commit, I also pushed it to GitHub.
2. Then **I wanted to clean up my feature branch**, by going back to the commit on master where the feature branch was created, by running

   ```
   git reset HEAD~3
   ```

   The unstaged changes shown by `git status` at this point was the accumulated changes done in the latest 3 commits, and was exactly what I hoped for after cleaning up. So I ran `git add` and `git commit` to commit them.
3. When I tried to push the commit to Github,

   ```
   $ git push origin feature
   To https://xxx
    ! [rejected]        feature -> feature (non-fast-forward)
   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://xxx'
   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
   ```

   Then I followed the hint by running `git pull`, which automatically
   merged the remote feature branch into my local feature branch, with
   no merge conflict because their tip commits are identical.

   However, the commits removed by `git reset
   HEAD~3` earlier show up again in the output of `git log`, and

   ```
   $ git status
   On branch feature
   Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature' by 2 commits.
     (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
   ```

   That **doesn't clean up my feature branch**, but add two new commits
   to the original feature branch. If I push to github, the remote
   feature branch will be the same.
   So do I miss anything? Or generally in similar cases, there is no need to clean up commits?

Comment: If you **have control**, you should've "force pushed" instead of pulling. This would reflect your history rewrite on github as well, instead of bringing back your original commits, which was what that pull did.

Comment: By "have control" I mean that nobody else is basing their work on the commits you intend to get rid of, like in this case, nobody else is working on that branch. If they are, you risk one of them pushing your removed commits back at a later time anyway, unless you get everybody to do fresh clones or rebase their work on your new commits.

Comment: Thanks. No one work on the same feature branch as i do.  I ran `git push origin feature`, and how can i "force pushed" instead?

Comment: Is it `git push origin feature --force`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12610763/156458

Answer (score 1):

Your workflow could use some improvement:

1. Do *not* push to remote after every commit. Only push after you have reached some kind of milestone where you are comfortable with what you've got and will unlikely make changes to these existing commits.
2. `git reset` is not the best way to clean up your work. Use `git rebase -i` instead. For instance, `git rebase -i HEAD~3` would allow you to edit one of the last 3 commits, or squash some of them.

Try those and you'll find yourself less likely stuck in a situation where you have to force push. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I ran git push origin feature, and how can I "force pushed" instead?

```
git push --force
```

Your branch should already have an upstream branch associated to it, so you don't need to add origin feature.

Now, since you already pulled, you should instead reset again (see "[Undo `git pull`, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35873436/6309)"), add, commit and force push.

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```