# how to revert git changes after merge and commit

Tags: git, github, merge, azure-devops, commit

I am new to git and don't have too much idea about how to use git.

I have committed my branch and pull it, then I changed to some other branch and again git pull it and then merge with my branch. Now I want to remove all the merged data and want to go till where I have committed my code.

I really need help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git pull, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state)

Answer (score 0):

Reset Your prev commit. `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

if you want to overwrite it on the server: `git push -f` **Be careful with force push** only do it when you are 100% sure your code is working.