# Pulled branch with deleted files with eGit

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

I've made a massive mistake and deleted several files directly on my remote repository. I pulled these changes thinking I would only be pulling the still present files, however I lost all the files on my local repository that I had deleted on the remote one. This caused my maven project to break and I couldn't do anything with it anymore. Is there any way to revert my changes?

Comment: In the _History_ view right-click the commit before the commits you pulled and choose _Reset > Hard_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General idea:

If your local files were committed, you can reset everything to before the git pull:

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

See [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to make sure `HEAD@{1}` is the right commit.
See [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1223354/6309).

---

For Eclipse itself, you can [go first to the reflog view](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/4._Reference#Git_Reflog_View)

[image: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/e/e3/Egit-1.2-reflog-view.png]

Then you can right-click on a past commit, and select "Reset > Hard"

Comment: This answer requires the installation of the Git command line to execute a single command that can also be executed via EGit.

Comment: @howlger True: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I realized I completely forgot to mark this as answered. Reflog really helped, thanks so much.