# how to revert an git accidental pull

Tags: git, bitbucket

Before committing my local change I have accidentally took a pull from master on to my release feature branch. The pull have made many conflicts within my local workspace.

Is there any way to revert the accidental master pull

When I triggered

```
git reflog --date=iso

c0ec509 HEAD@{2018-12-24 15:55:10 +0530}: clone: from https://bitbucket.com/scm/myproject.git
```

but the pull which I have done is at `2018-12-28 01:29`

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo git pull, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+pull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `git reset --merge`. This will abort the merge you have started.

Comment: will this removes my uncommitted changes (which I needs to commit)

Comment: No it will not remove your changes. It should reset all to the state before merging. But for sure you can make a copy of all your local repo.

Comment: what is the difference between  `git reset --merge` and `git reset --soft`

Comment: git reset --soft only reset index, while git reset--merge also revert changes between commit your trying to merge and HEAD, but it will not touch uncommited changes.

Comment: `git reset --merge` is a very old way to spell `git merge --abort`.

Comment: You shouldn’t have been able to merge if there were uncommitted changes in the working directory

Answer (score 2):

> `git merge --abort` to abort the merge.
>
> `git reset --hard <commitId>` to reset to a specific commit, **you
>   will lose anything**.
>
> `git reset --soft <commitId>` to reset to a specific commit, keeps
>   uncommitted changes.

To make sure you do not lose your local commit you can use `git stash` before doing anything and `git stash pop` when everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

In order to keep your uncommited changes try:

`git reset --soft`

Comment: does `git reset --soft` have any benefits over `git reset --merge`

Comment: For details please see: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset

Comment: when I did `git reset --soft` I got 
`fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge.`

Comment: It means your merge is not completed yet, Please try elp's answer

Comment: how abt `git reset --merge`

Comment: I havent personally tried it but the definition suggests it should work as well:
`Resets the index and updates the files in the working tree that are different between <commit> and HEAD, but keeps those which are different between the index and working tree (i.e. which have changes which have not been added).`