# Extract Stackoverflow Question Counter using Geb

Tags: java, grails, geb

I would be interested in collecting statistics on what are the most upvoted questions on SO. Using Geb, I tried to extract the relevant HTML:

```
@Integration
class PlayTestsSpec extends GebSpec {
    void "check stackoverflow"() {
        when: "Go to so"
            go "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state"
        $('#sidebar.show-votes div.related.js-gps-related-questions').children()
        then:
            System.out.println("Done.")
    }
}
```

I actually end up with an array (?) of divs:

```
[<div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">, <div class="spacer">]
```

How would I iterate over each of these divs and extract the vote counter and question title?

Answer (score 0):

Create a [`RelatedQuestionModule`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/1.0/#repeating-content) and then use `children().moduleList(RelatedQuestionModule)`.

Better, use the [Stack Overflow Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries), which is meant for this sort of thing.