# How to revert Laravel app to state before pull?

Tags: git

In Laravel 6 application with git on bitbucket  I have several branches and having current branchA
I had to switch to branchB and make pull from the git
and I run command

```
git pull  origin  feature/branchB
```

but seems I missed firstly to run command

```
git checkout feature/branchB
```

Now my app raise strange errors

Which is valid way to check current status of branchA with pulling from git and revert to prior state?

Thanks!

Comment: If the output of `git status` tells you that "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/...' by n commits", that might give you a clue on how many commits you should go back. You could use `git reset --hard HEAD~n` for undoing those commits you pulled, where `n` is the number of commits you want to reset. Just first check your `git log` to see if those are really the commits you want to reset.

Comment: Also, this question is more about git (if not exclusively) than it is about Laravel - just a suggestion :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo git pull, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223354/undo-git-pull-how-to-bring-repos-to-old-state)