# How to redo git pull?

Tags: git, git-pull

For example, I am working on branch1 and I want to 'git pull' code from branch2. However, I 'git pull' code from branch3 instead of branch2. How can I redo the 'git pull' command? (delete the code from branch2)

Comment: just `git reset --hard  sha` with sha the commit it of branch1 before pull

Comment: A pull is just a fetch + a merge. Look for how to undo a merge.

Comment: Do you confuse `git pull`, that syncs with a *remote repository* with `git switch` that changes branches? I down voted because 
[No research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just pulled, as described in "[Undo `git pull`, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69253352/6309)", a simple `git reset --hard custom-branch@{1}` should be enough, assuming you have no work in prigress (or it would be lost, erased by the `reset --hard`)

You can then `git fetch`,  and `git merge origin/anyBranchYouNeed`, to make the pull you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
git reset --hard <commit-id>
```

(kindly commit your code before that, `--hard` will make you loose the uncommitted changes)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for you answer